# App showing doing too much work in main thread even if the operations are performed in background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-asynctask, worker-thread

Hi I am getting this message in log every time when execute query. But query is executing in background thread only and Table has not more 500 rows and also I always apply limit 100.
Please don't simply give some link and say this question already answered.

I have read lots of answers in SO regarding this. But still it did not solved my issue. can anybody give me proper reason or solution to my problem?

Choreographer: Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Following is my runnable class and I am calling it like  new Thread(new MessageLoaderThread(limit)).start();

```
private class MessageLoaderThread implements Runnable {

        int limit;
        ArrayList<MESSAGE_HEADER> result;

        public MessageLoaderThread(int limit) {
            this.limit = limit;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            showProgressRing(true);

           result = Helper.getRows("Select * from TABLE_NAME LIMIT "+limit);

                    if (result != null) {
                        int count = result.size();

                        if (count > 0) {
                            firstVisibleMessageSeqId = result.get(0).getsequenceId();
                            lastVisibleMessageSeqId = result.get(count - 1).getsequenceId();
                        }
                    }

            if (result != null && result.size() > 0) {
                updateAdapter(result);
            }
            showProgressRing(false);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't immediately see an issue. A complete [mcve] will likely be necessary.

Comment: Maybe you are doing too much work inside "updateAdapter(result)"_

Answer (score 0):

I know that you already read a lot of questions. Have you tried to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? Its the default for multi threading in Android.

Try to not update your adapter inside your thread. Android perform some animations when you change some views. Wait the thread to finish and then update your view.

Comment: I tried asynctask I had the same issue so for that reason I shifted to Thread concept.

Comment: You should not call any View operation in background threads. Try to update the adapter after the thread finishes. 
Try to update the adapter in [postExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still getting the warning after using `AsyncTask` it is probably because the operations are still heavy and long running. Try using other apis from `java.util.concurrent` as suggested in the `AsyncTask` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> AsyncTask is designed to be a helper class around Thread and Handler
>   and does not constitute a generic threading framework. AsyncTasks
>   should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the
>   most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time,
>   it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the
>   java.util.concurrent package such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and
>   FutureTask.

Comment: Thanks:) @AndroidMechanic I'll try and let you know.